"Localization at a prime" tensor with "the quotient by that prime power"
Let $R$ be a ring, and $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal in $R$, I want to understand the tensor product
$$
R_{\mathfrak{p}} \otimes_{R} R/\mathfrak{p}^k,
$$
where $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is $R$ localizaed at $\mathfrak{p}$ (formally invert all elements not in $\mathfrak{p}$).
I am uncertain how to approach this. If we let $S:=R - \mathfrak{p}$, then using exactness of the localization functor we have
$$
S^{-1}R \otimes_{R} R/\mathfrak{p}^k \cong S^{-1}(R/\mathfrak{p}^k) \cong S^{-1}R/S^{-1}\mathfrak{p}^k.
$$
But I am uncertain what the ideal $S^{-1}\mathfrak{p}^k$ looks like in $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$.
I also tried to work out what is $\mathbb{Z}_{(2)} \otimes \mathbb{Z}/(8)$, but I don't really know how to do this as well.

You get $R_{\mathfrak{p}}\otimes_RR/\mathfrak{p}^k=R_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p}^kR_{\mathfrak{p}}$. If $k=1$, this is the residue field of the local ring $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$, which is alternatively the quotient field of the integral domain $R/\mathfrak{p}$. I'm not sure if you can expect a better description for $k>1$.

The ring cannot be simplified more. So this is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Please notice that comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, I suggest to post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list.

@Thorgott I was expecting something like $R_\mathfrak{p} \otimes_R R/\mathfrak{p}^k = R/\mathfrak{p}^k$, since intuitively everything that is coprime to $\mathfrak{p}$ is already a unit. Is it possible to impose some conditions to make this true? By your argument for $k=1$ case we will at least need $\mathfrak{p}$ to be maximal, is that enough?

In fact I think my suggestion is true if $R$ is a PID, for general rings there is not much that be said here.

There are canonical isomorphisms of $R$-algebras
$$
R_{\mathfrak{p}}\otimes_RR/\mathfrak{p}^k\cong R_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p}^kR_{\mathfrak{p}}\cong(R/\mathfrak{p}^k)_{\mathfrak{p}}\cong(R/\mathfrak{p}^k)_{\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}^k},
$$
the first three of which you have already observed. For the last isomorphism, it is only important to keep track of the meaning. Here, $(R/\mathfrak{p}^k)_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is the localization (as an $R$-algebra) of $R/\mathfrak{p}^k$ at the prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $R$ and $(R/\mathfrak{p}^k)_{\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}^k}$ is the localization (as a commutative ring) of $R/\mathfrak{p}^k$ at the prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}^k$ of $R/\mathfrak{p}^k$ (and this is an $R$-algebra a fortiori). The isomorphism is given by reducing the denominator of a fraction mod $\mathfrak{p}^k$ (which is an isomorphism because $\mathfrak{p}^k$ acts trivially on $R/\mathfrak{p}^k$).
If $k=1$, the final term is alternatively known as the quotient field of the integral domain $R/\mathfrak{p}$. This is called the residue field of $R$ at $\mathfrak{p}$ and often denoted $\kappa(\mathfrak{p})$ in algebro-geometric contexts.
In the comments, you are wondering when the canonical map $R/\mathfrak{p}^k\rightarrow R_{\mathfrak{p}}\otimes_RR/\mathfrak{p}^k$ is an isomorphism and this is the case if and only if $R/\mathfrak{p}^k$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}^k$ by the last description. The correspondence between prime ideals of $R/\mathfrak{p}^k$ and prime ideals of $R$ containing $\mathfrak{p}^k$ (equivalently, containing $\mathfrak{p}$) makes it clear that this is the case if and only if $\mathfrak{p}$ is a maximal ideal of $R$.
